# Goodness-of-fit test to use for weighted data

Tags: chi-squared-test, modeling, goodness-of-fit, text-mining, weighted-data

*Hello. I'm working on a AP stats project,  but since what I'm doing is beyond the scope of what we do in class (i.e. learn how to use a calculator), I think it's safe to say this isn't a homework question.*

What I'm trying to accomplish is extract some statistics (e.g. word frequencies, sentence lengths) from texts by various authors (with the help of [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/)), and then attempt to match "mystery" texts to those authors based on the similarity of those statistics. From what I understand, I'm looking for a goodness-of-fit test.

For word frequency tables, I think a chi-square GOF test is the way to go, since I am comparing an observed frequency distribution to a known one. However, I would like to combine this data (specifically the p-value?) with other statistics, such as average sentence length or dialogue-narration ratio, to get more accurate comparison. Ideally, I would like to be able to weight each statistic as well, since some (e.g. word frequencies) should count more than others (e.g. punctuation frequencies). What sort of test should I use for this scenario? I'm not sure if it's legal to weight the observations in a chi-square test, or if doing so would actually work. Also, the p-values would not be integers.

*Sidenote: When I asked my teacher whether I could simply multiply each category by a constant to weight them, he kinda just shrugged at me*

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to assume that the vocabulary is independent of the text structure, then you can add up the $\chi^2$ you are getting from the word distribution to the $\chi^2$ from sentence length distribution to the $\chi^2$ from dialogue-narration ratio. Be mindful of unique words -- Pearson test assumes that cell sizes are sufficiently large.